# Excel VBA - adding rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code that adds rows where I need them based on information in column C.

```
Dim lRow As Long
    For sRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        If Cells(sRow, "C") <> Cells(sRow - 1, "C") Then Rows(sRow).EntireRow.Insert
    Next sRow
```

The result I get for this is that a row is inserted at row 15 (where my table headings are located), moving those table headings down to row 16. Then another row is inserted between table headings and content at row 17. Then rows are inserted at the desired locations from there on.

How can I change this so that this begins at row 16 and only inserts a new row when the content in column C changes?

Here's what I'm looking for:
[image]

and here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Each time the script runs, it will push the whole table down one row.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from row 16, just change the starting point in the for loop

```
Dim lRow As Long
    For sRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 16 Step -1
        If Cells(sRow, "C") <> Cells(sRow - 1, "C") Then Rows(sRow).EntireRow.Insert
    Next sRow
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Tom, but this does not produce the desired effect. I've added what's happening in my original post. This still pushed the table down one row, adds a row after table headings, and then doesn't add any more rows after that.

Comment: Ok, please see updated; i've changed the 3 to 16 from your original code.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get it.  You're just inserting a row where there's a difference in the 'C' column.  Unfortunately, that includes your header.  Thy this:

```
Dim lRow As Long
    For sRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
        If Cells(sRow, "C") <> Cells(sRow - 1, "C") and Cells(sRow - 1, "C").Value <> "Or Ty" Then 
            Rows(sRow).EntireRow.Insert
        End If 
    Next sRow
```